# Remove RDD values with condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD like this:

```
[ (Person 1, [Cat, Dog, Cow]), (Person 2, [Cat]), (Person 3,[Cow, Chicken])]
```

And I have a list of frequent animals:

```
freq_animals=[Cat, Dog]
```

I want to delete in my RDD the values for each person that are not in the list of frequent animals i.e. Output would be:

```
[ (Person 1, [Cat, Dog]), (Person 2, [Cat]), (Person 3,[])]
```

Any idea how I could change my RDD?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `mapValues` using a list comprehension:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("Person 1", ["Cat", "Dog", "Cow"]), ("Person 2", ["Cat"]), ("Person 3", ["Cow", "Chicken"])])

freq_animals = ["Cat", "Dog"]

rdd2 = rdd.mapValues(lambda v: [i for i in v if i in freq_animals])

print(rdd2.collect())
# [('Person 1', ['Cat', 'Dog']), ('Person 2', ['Cat']), ('Person 3', [])]
```